# Python Sh Library for MySQL dump import using output redirection (<) pipes

Tags: python, mysql, pipe, sh

I am using Python Sh (https://amoffat.github.io/sh/) and I was wondering if its possible to use `<>` pipes as well?

Mainly I am talking about `mysql < dump.sql`.
I was thinking about using `mysql -D db -e "source mydump.sql'` but `source` is not recommended for that.

Is there any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the STDIN Processing (http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#stdin-processing) and Redirection (http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#redirection) sections of the document. That said, your code:

```
mysql < dump.sql
```

should be equivalent to:

```
dump_file = open("home/user/dump.sql", "r")
sh.mysql(_in=dump_file)
dump_file.close()
```